# Is it possible to return a reference from a closure in PHP?

Tags: php, closures

In order to return a reference from a function in PHP one must:

> ...use the reference operator & in
>   both the function declaration and when assigning the returned value to
>   a variable.

This ends up looking like:

```
function &func() { return $ref; }
$reference = &func();
```

I am trying to return a reference from a closure. In in a simplified example, what I want to achieve is:

```
$data['something interesting'] = 'Old value';

$lookup_value = function($search_for) use (&$data) {
    return $data[$search_for];
}

$my_value = $lookup_value('something interesting');
$my_value = 'New Value';

assert($data['something interesting'] === 'New Value');
```

I cannot seem to get the regular syntax for returning references from functions working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
$data['something interesting'] = 'Old value';

$lookup_value = function & ($search_for) use (&$data) {
    return $data[$search_for];
};

$my_value = &$lookup_value('something interesting');
$my_value = 'New Value';

assert($data['something interesting'] === 'New Value');
```

Check [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures) out:

Comment: Got it in one. Another bizarre choice of sytax to remember. Thanks!